# Mysql Event runs but not "stay"

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-event

I've got Mysql 5.5 
I created a storred procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `refresh_mobileTemp`() 
BEGIN
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mobileTemp;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE  mobileTemp AS 
(SELECT distinct
...
 );

END
```

running

```
call refresh_mobileTemp();
```

The temp table is created.

Than I dropped the temp table and created an Event:

```
CREATE  EVENT `schedulerMobileTemp` 
 ON SCHEDULE every 10 SECOND
 ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
DO 
  CALL refresh_mobileTemp();
```

every 10 seconds in process list appears a process that create the temp table 
[image]but than if I call `select * from mobileTemp` it returns: Error Code: 1146. Table 'mobileTemp' doesn't exist

What I'm missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Temporary tables live only inside the session that creates them, and only until that session finishes. Oh thats the MYSQL session by the way

Answer (score 3):

[As explained in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-temporary-table):

> A TEMPORARY table is visible only to the current session, and is
>   dropped automatically when the session is closed.

It means the temporary table is visible and usable only within the event that creates it.